# How to navigate to custom page when user taps on a Twilio Chat SDK push notification

Tags: twilio, twilio-api, twilio-programmable-chat

I have read both the Android and iOS SDK documentation for integrating push notifications into my chat implementation. One topic that I do not see discussed is how to navigate to the correct place in an application when a push notification is tapped on.

For instance when a use taps on a push notification how does an app respond to the event in order to navigate to the view of the channel that received the message?

Answer (score 0):

The documentation [Push Notifications on iOS](https://www.twilio.com/docs/chat/ios/push-notifications-ios) do not reference it but digging into the iOS SDK I found [TwilioChatClientDelegate Protocol Reference](https://media.twiliocdn.com/sdk/ios/chat/releases/2.4.6/docs/Protocols/TwilioChatClientDelegate.html#//api/name/chatClient:notificationAddedToChannelWithSid:). It has a delegate that does what I was looking for:

```
– chatClient:notificationNewMessageReceivedForChannelSid:messageIndex:
– chatClient:notificationAddedToChannelWithSid:
– chatClient:notificationInvitedToChannelWithSid:
– chatClient:notificationRemovedFromChannelWithSid:
– chatClient:notificationUpdatedBadgeCount:
```

For Android there is [com.twilio.chat.NotificationPayload Class Reference](https://media.twiliocdn.com/sdk/android/chat/releases/4.0.4/docs/classcom_1_1twilio_1_1chat_1_1NotificationPayload.html) which has methods for parsing out the data from the notification payload.